# AngularJS: data binding between expressions and sessionstorage

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular. I have a single page application with a navbar which maps to some html "sections". Each section is visualized monitoring the state of a variable by the Angular directives `ng-show`.

**After the first load** all my sections are loaded and all HTML is in the browser. Now I can do some operations and save an object in sessionStorage. But the Angular expression referred to it does not load new data! 
I would like a classical data binding between my expression and my session storage. How can I do this?

Here there is a snippet of my html:

```
    <div class="container" ng-show="panels.isSelected(2)" ng-controller="DataController as pdc">
        {{pdc.myData.property_foo}}         
    </div>
```

and this is the controller to load data from sessionStorage

```
.controller('DataController', ['$window',  function($window) {

  pdc = this;

  //myData is an object
  pdc.myData = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem("myData"));

}]);
```

Angular evaluates the value of `myData` only at the first loading of the page, instead of triggering a new evaluation of the expression each times `myData` changes...that's my problem...

> Edit: I simulate my problem in this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/vG1IGOPsJlbUPOzYsY03?p=preview As you can see, when you press update the value displayed from session storage is not updated. You can see new values only by refreshing the page.

Comment: not clear what you mean by `myData changes`. How is it being changed ? The changes should be connected by a service probably so that you are changing the live object before storing in sessionstorage

Comment: i.e. when I press a button a function is triggered passing `myDataObject`. This function does something like: `$window.sessionStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(myDataObject));`

Comment: @superciccio14 check out forked plunker ;)

Comment: @rzysia can you post the link of forked plunker? I had a problem with plnkr... thanks : )

Comment: @superciccio14 aww, it overhelmed me, I don't know how to update it for all :P I just added one line, as it's in my answer - `pdc.myData = value;` into update function and myData was updated after click "Update" button ;)

Comment: @superciccio14 ok, I've created a new one ;)
http://plnkr.co/edit/wwoiChlrliQ59lRBT7j0?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to `$scope.$watch` to evaluate data that is not present on `$scope`. For instance, `sessionStorage`, `this`, `SomeService` or any data source *really.*

So, to do what you are asking you should inject `$scope` into your controller, set up a `$watch` for the return value of a function, and update `this.myData` to said value.

```
app.controller('DataController', ['$window',  '$scope', function($window, $scope) {

  pdc = this;

  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $window.sessionStorage.getItem('myData');
  }, function (value) {
    pdc.myData = value;
  });

  pdc.update = function ( value ) {

    $window.sessionStorage.setItem("myData", value);

  };

}]);
```

Alternatively, you could reverse this (makes a little bit more sense in my opinion):

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return pdc.myData;
}, function (value) {
  $window.sessionStorage.setItem('myData', value);
});

pdc.update = function (value) {
  pdc.myData = value;
};
```

**[updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tu1qrgqfG9H4c6hnMh3q?p=preview)**

Comment: Wow it works! I prefer not using $scope since I'm using [Controller As](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax

Comment: That's all good and well, but you will need some sort of medium to connect the sessionStorage with `pdc`. To rid yourself of the $scope injection, you could utilize [Object getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to achieve something similar.

Comment: Oh and please dont forget to accept the given answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is super-helpful but I'm still looking for a way to fix my problem without passing via `$scope`

Comment: In other words: isn't there a way to have a 2-ways data binding with _view_ and _session storage_ like happens for _views <> models_

Comment: No, `sessionStorage` lives outside the world of angular. You have to manually let angular know that the sessionStorage has been updated and trigger the appropriate event (in this case, a `$digest` through the `$watch`).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I have another question but is off from this topic. Accepted : )

Answer (score 2):

Expressions, which are simply in controller, are called once - when controller is loaded. So your updating **wont** changing myData value. What you should do is to add updating myData in your `update` function:

```
pdc.update = function ( value ) {
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem("myData", value);
    pdc.myData = value;
};
```

Comment: wow, it works! My real code is a bit more complicated of that plnkr but now I have understood the logic. As you can see in my first post, I have a @rzysia controller for reading local storage value in that piece of html. That snippet of html is displayed only after pressing an update button. I update the value  `pdc.myData = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem("myData"))` but why does not work?

Comment: because value written in input isn't JSON object - it's simple plain text, no need to parse it

Comment: @superciccio14 try update with this: `pdc.myData = $window.sessionStorage.getItem("myData");`

Comment: In my real code myData is an object...my problem still lies in the update of value referred to session Storage in different snippets of html loaded only once. Here is a plnkr where you can see the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/gFqHPw2frdL38PkWo81x?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 has a plugin to work with local and session storage and its called **Angular-Storage**.

It works like this:

1. First you implement this plugin in the definition of your app:

`angular.module('angularStorageApp', ['angular-storage']);`

2. To set an object in your storage you use this:

`angular.module('angularStorageApp').controller('testCtrl', function(store) {
         store.set('obj', myObj);
    }`

3. To get an object from your storage you use this:

`angular.module('angularStorageApp').controller('testCtrl', function(store) {
        var myObjSaved = store.get('obj');
    }`

**Downloads:**

Angular-Storage for production:

[Angular Storage .min](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage/blob/master/dist/angular-storage.min.js)

Angular-Storage for development:

[Angular Storage](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage/blob/master/dist/angular-storage.js)

Comment: My problem is not saving and loading data in local storage. I need a way to trigger the evaluation of the expression each times `myData` changes in local storage...

Comment: I have just tried to use the library in this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/jll5PnUbPD06RD9xOpgZ?p=preview but it did not fix my problem :(